# Getting weird exception while setting value to virtual fields using Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I followed this [article](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html) for understanding Mongoose Virtual attributes.

Version of Mongoose node module am using : `"mongoose": "~3.8.8"`

This is how my Mongoose model looks like :

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var StatusSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: String
}, {
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
});


StatusSchema.virtual('count')
    .get(function () {
        return this.count;
    })
    .set(function (count) {
        this.count = count;
    });

mongoose.model('status', StatusSchema);
```

In Node controller i have accessed this **Status model** and trying to set value to `count` virtual variable :

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    StatusModel = mongoose.model('status');

.....

function populateStatusCounts() {
    var statusModel = new StatusModel();
    statusModel.count = 123;
}
```

Following is the exception am confronting :

```
Schema.prototype.pathType = function (path) {
                                     ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Schema.pathType (F:\talent-pool\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:435:38)
    at model.Document.set (F:\talent-pool\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:481:30)
```

I have no clue about what wrong am i doing here ? Any help would be appreciated, as am stuck with this from pretty long time.

PS : Am new to this Node and MongoDB / Mongoose world !